# How can I get an empty Builder for a model?

Tags: laravel, builder

Lets say I have a function that returns a builder. In case this builder cannot be returned, I want to return an empty builder - meaning, a builder which doesn't point to any data. One which if you do a get(), you will get empty collection. Any idea?

Comment: I think you mean a builder without any restrictions, i.e. if you do a get you will get every row. This would fit to your selected answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
$builder = Post::query();
```

Comment: This is different from what the OP asked: If you call get() on this query it will return all values in the database instead of nothing as OP required. However, this was useful for me since I wanted exactly this behavior.

Comment: @VinGarcia I think the OP was just asking for the wrong thing. This is an empty builder.

Answer (score 6):

If your model has primary key, you can do this as a workaround:

```
   $builder = Post::query()->whereNull('id')
```

Comment: That's still going to hit the database though, so not ideal

Comment: is there any other way to do this without searching the database.